# AWS: What Happens to Static S3 Files When a New Instance of a Website is Deployed?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, web-deployment, aws-lambda

So a little background.  We have a website (js, jquery, less, node) that is hosted on Amazon AWS S3 and is distributed using CloudFront.  In the past we have stored our resources statically in the `assets` folder within app locally and on S3.

Recently we have set up a node lambda that listens to Kinesis events and generates a json file that is then stored within the `assets` folder in S3.  Currently, the file in the bucket with the same key is overwritten and the site using the generated file as it should.

My questions is, what happens to that json file when we deploy a new instance of our website? Even if we remove the json file from the local assets folder, if the deployment overwrites the whole assets directory in the S3 project when a new one is deployed, does that result in the json file being removed?

Thanks in advance!
Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on how you'r syncing files, I recommend you use the "sync" command so that only new files are uploaded and only if you specify to delete a file that doesn't exist in your repo but it exists in S3 it will get deleted, otherwise not.

See for example the CLI command docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html ... as you can see, if you specify --delete the files will be deleted.

But not sure what's your use case, do you want that file to get deleted? It seems that you don't want that :)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Currently we are using serverless's meta-sync to sync our environmental variables and everything else is managed manually and deployed with the projects (so no syncs for these guys).

Comment: got it, so the answer to your question is NO, file won't be deleted unless you remove it manually. This is because S3 is a key/value storage, even if you see folder structures (actually in the console you have a button that says "Create Folder") it is not a folder per se, it is just a part of the key for the object (which will be the file) ... so when you upload a whole directory it replaces only the objects that match with the key (folder structure + file name)